# Singleton abusing?

Tags: c++, singleton

I have some manager like resource manager which is being singleton. Some objects do need to call method of this manager. Does this practice smell bed?

```
some object logic: ResourceManager::init()->callMethod();
```

We are not using reference to the singleton, we're getting it during the runtime. Is it suitable?

Comment: Why do you think this is abusing the singleton class?  The singleton pattern restricts the instantiation of a class to one object, which is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system. It doesn't put any restrictions on calling its methods.

Comment: Calling it `init` 'smells bad' (only the first call will initialize, so the name is very misleading, something like `getInstance()` would be more appropriate). But otherwise this looks like a pretty standard way of using singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singleton pattern has its pros and cons, but if you're using it then what you have written isn't too terrible.

I would however strongly suggest renaming init() to something more like getInstance() if that is what that function is returning.

As far as your usage is concerned, the only real negative in writing

```
a::getInstance()->foo();
a::getInstance()->bar();
```

instead of

```
a* thing = a::getInstance();
thing->foo();
thing->bar();
```

would be potential extra function call overhead if the getInstance() function hasn't been inlined.

Generally if you're going to be using the same singleton a bunch of times inside a single function the calling getInstance() once would be slighly better, but ultimately I think it'd be more of a coding style issue over any real performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

The healthy way to use singleton is pretty simple:

class ResourceManager { ... }; 
// implement the class as normal

ResourceManager& GetResMan() { ... } 
// global access point that summons and retuns the instance, that may be a local static, a static at filename scope, or even may use additional creation tricks for corner cases

*Document* it as a thing providing a singleton.

GetResMan().DoStuff();
// usage at client site

From here whether it is good or bad depends on the application logic/design whether you actually mean to have a singleton for that manager -- if you're positive you may safely ignore the bashing campaigns.

A refined version could have two access functions, the mainstream returning const ref so you can easily tell the mutating client calls from the rest. But it depends on the nature of the class, and its use cases.